# What does the following line accomplish?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was trying to solve an algorithm and while trying to find other solutions to it, I found one which was very short and very fast, just one problem...I can't seem to understand what this line is doing:

Full solution:

```
def proper_fractions(n):
    phi = n > 1 and n
    print(phi)
    for p in range(2, int(n ** .5) + 1):
        if not n % p:
            phi -= phi // p
            while not n % p:
                n //= p
    if n > 1: phi -= phi // n
    return phi
```

Line that I don't understand:

```
phi = n > 1 and n
```

Please forgive me If it is very easy to understand, I just have never come across something like this, I've only used `and` in `if` statements, here is what I changed the line to (I think it works like the other one, but not sure how the other one does exactly what the following line which I changed does):

```
phi = n if n > 1 else False
```

Please could someone clear-up how the line that I don't understand works?

Comment: `False` is also equal to `0`.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I'm aware that 0 is falsy but I still don't understand what 'that' line does, how does it even assign n if `n > 1`?

Comment: That's not what I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), Python logical operators are not necessarily "purely Boolean". In particular, `and` and `or` are not actually guaranteed to return `True` or `False`. Instead, they return one of their operands. Here's how Python defines the value of `x and y`:

*if x is false, then x, else y*

"False" in this context does not mean that `x` has to be the value `False`. Instead, it just has to be anything with a falsy value, like a zero of any type or an empty sequence or collection.

In this case, when `n > 1` evaluates `False`, the operator short-circuits and returns `n > 1`, AKA `False`. But if `n > 1` evaluates `True`, the operator simply returns `n` without modifying it in any way, as the docs describe.

Answer (score 2):

The *truth table* for `a and b` looks like this:

```py
True  and True  == True
True  and False == False
False and True  == False
False and False == False
```

We can observe three things:

- When `a` is `True`, the result is always the same as `b`.
- When `a` is `False`, the result is always `False`, in other words, it is always the same as `a`.
- When `a` is `False`, `b` is completely irrelevant, so we don't even need to evaluate it.

Note that in Python, [`True` and `False` are *not* the only objects that have a boolean value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). In fact, *every single object* in Python has a boolean value. E.g. `0` has a *falsey* value, `"Hello"` has a *truthy* value, and so on.

So, with the optimizations we discovered about the truth table, and the added condition that we need to handle values other than `True` and `False`, we can construct the following, revised, truth table:

```py
a and b == a # if `a` is *falsey*
a and b == b # if `a` is *truthy*
```

This matches up with [the documentation of `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Similar reasoning applies to `or`:

```py
a or b == b # if `a` is *falsey*
a or b == a # if `a` is *truthy*
```

So, the result of the line in question:

> ```py
> phi = n > 1 and n
> ```

will be that `phi` is assigned `False` if `n <= 1` and `n` if `n > 1`.

The further computation that is performed with `phi` in turn works because `False` is equivalent to `0` in a numeric context, i.e.

```py
False + 1 ==  1
False - 1 == -1
```

This makes the rest of the algorithm work, which contains statements like:

```py
phi -= phi // p
```

Where arithmetic is performed with the value of `phi`.

See [the documentation on the numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) for details, which contains the following statement [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> There are three distinct numeric types: *integers*, *floating point numbers*, and *complex numbers*. In addition, **Booleans are a subtype of integers**.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's first checking if the first evaluation is True or False (Null value are considered false). Then if it's True, will return the second value. In this case, n.

More details:

```
> if n = 3
> 1. phi = n > 1 and n
> 2. phi = 3 > 1 and 3
> 3. phi = True and 3
> 4. phi = 3
```

Comment: How does `True and True` become 3?

Comment: Close! But there's no Boolean conversion of the second operand at all, because there doesn't need to be. If the first operand is truthy, `and` just returns the second operand. This produces the correct result whether the second operand is truthy or falsy.

Comment: It's first checking if the evaluation if True and if so, the latest value checked is assigned. In this case, it's n.

Answer (score 1):

From section 6.11 of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> Note that neither and nor or restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if s is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression s or 'foo' yields the desired value. Because not has to create a new value, it returns a boolean value regardless of the type of its argument (for example, not 'foo' produces False rather than ''.)

So it first check if n > 1, if it is true, then it return s n, otherwise it returns False.